# Why does [[nodiscard]] only encourage compiler to issue a warning and does not require it?

Tags: c++, c++17, standards, nodiscard, terminology

The `[[nodiscard]]` attribute introduced in C++17 standard, and in case of the

> ... potentially-evaluated discarded-value expression,..., implementations are **encouraged** to issue a warning in such cases.

Source: [n4659, C++17 final working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf).

Similar phrasing is used on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard), that in case of "violation":

> the compiler is **encouraged** to issue a warning.

Why is the word **encouraged** used instead of **required**? Are there situations (except, the explicit cast to `void`) when a compiler is better off not issuing a warning? What is the reason behind softening the standard language in the particular case of relatively safe requirement to issue a warning no matter what (again, except, say, explicit cast to void)?

Comment: Are *any* warnings required in C++?

Comment: @JohnZwinck very good point. That probably is the reason for the choice of the language in the standard related to encouraging\discouraging warnings. But now I obviously have a more general question.

Comment: One thing this does is allow implementations to ignore the attribute. The guideline the standards committee uses is that attributes should ignorable without changes to semantics (other than optimizations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard specifies the behavior of a valid C++ program. In so doing, it also defines what "valid C++ program" means.

Diagnostics are only required for code which is ill-formed, code which is syntactically or semantically incorrect (and even then, there are some ill-formed circumstances that don't require diagnostics). Either the code is well-formed, or it is ill-formed and (usually) a diagnostic is displayed.

So the very idea of a "warning" is just not something the C++ standard recognizes, or is *meant* to recognize. Notice that even the "implementations are encouraged to issue a warning" statement is in a non-normative notation, rather than a legitimate specification of behavior.